# regex - compatible of reset match (\K) in microsoft regex

Tags: regex, vba

```
Dim rg As New RegExp
rg.pattern = "3456" '"12\K3456" in others engine
rg.Global = 1
Dim result As MatchCollection, m As Match
Set result = rg.Execute("123456 3456")
For Each m In result
    Debug.Print m.FirstIndex, m.Value
Next
```

found two matchs, 
how can i find only the one match "**3456**" of "12**3456**" in MS regex (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vbscript.dll)

Comment: The regex engine doesn't support the `\k` option. Either use `Debug.Print m.SubMatches(1)` with `rg.pattern = "12(3456)"`, or `rg.pattern = "123456"` and then `Debug.Print Mid(m, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

```
        string pattern = @"3456";
        string input = @"123456";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
}
```

?? Your description is very bad

Comment: my pattern is "123456" , i am search the index of "3456" ,"12" is also a part of the condition, in case of "123456 23456" there is only one match

Comment: Do you want one match or more matches

Comment: in this case : "123456 3456", one math of first "3456", i am searce for "123456" bu i need the first index of  "3456"